# Jenkins slave would not launch my metro app

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-8, jenkins

I have a c# application (metroLauncher) in which I have used a IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication manager to launch my metro app for automation. I can launch my metro app by running the metroLauncher.exe (which is created after building my c# application).

I have written a batch to run metroLauncher.exe. Problem is when this batch file is run through Jenkins , it does not launches the app.

App launches fine when the batch file is run through command line directly.

Can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the page https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/My+software+builds+on+my+computer+but+not+on+Jenkins especially under the title *Desktop access*